# C++11 string properties and gcc version

Tags: c++, string, c++11, gcc, stdstring

I currently use C++ string properties and specifically its pop_back() fonction. As written in the title, it leads to an error (same error seen ini an other topic) :

```
‘std::string’ has no member named ‘pop_back’
```

But what's strange is that I already use C++11 specific properties (as "auto" for iterators, etc.) and I never get any error.

For information, I build my code under Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.6.3. For me, this version is good enough. I also put "-std=c++0x" flag so I really don't know where is the point ?!

Moreover, I've seen, in previous topic, that it's better to use "-std=c++11" flag now. But when I try this, the following error appears :

```
unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’
```

Comment: GCC 4.6 has only partial support for C++11. `-std=c++11` is only in GCC 4.7 and later. I suspect the same is true for `std::string::pop_back()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On gcc 4.6 (which had only partial support for the new standard) the option is **-std=c++0x** because at that time the release date (i.e., 2011) was still unknown.